# Registering purchased consumable at a server using some kind of identifier

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

Having a bit of trouble with consumable in-app purchases.

Here's my setup:

I have an iOS client and a server. The server provides some kind of querying service (specifics irrelevant).

Each time the iOS client queries the server, I want to "consume" a consumable purchase. So basically, each search/query costs one consumable.

Here's what I originally thought of doing:

- Client sends purchase request to StoreKit
- StoreKit replies to Client with receipt
- Client sends receipt and apple ID to server
- Server verifies receipt and sends success to client
- Client finishes transaction at StoreKit

Now for each query:

- Client sends apple id (+ query data) to server
- Server checks if given apple id still has remaining queries
- Server replies to client with either query result or error if not enough queries remain for apple ID.

Now for the kicker:

I can't get the apple ID as it turns out. So I'm kind of stuck...

Does anyone have any experience with this? I could do it all on the client, but I want it to be secure.

Comment: Couldn't you generate a unique identifier for each client and use that in place of the apple ID?

Comment: UDIDs have been deprecated and new apps using them will not be accepted according to some research I've been doing.

Comment: Just a UUID sent back from the server to the client? Granted this means the client has to remember it.. (I know nothing of this :-)

Comment: Tovi, I didn't mean to use UDIDs.  I mean you can create your own identifier.  ie. the server assigns the first client to use your app identifier '1'.  The client saves this and uses it in all communications with the server. etc. etc.

Comment: Hmmm, ok, that sounds a bit better, but that still has the problem of what to do when a user loses his iPhone, buys a new one, or wipes his client in some other way. AppleID's seem the only way to go exactly because they are individual bound and not device bound.

Comment: As you've already got a server set up, you could create your own account log-in system.  Require an email address, username, and password.  Then they can log in on any device.  There is rarely only one way to go :)

Comment: I know, but i was really hoping to avoid a registration process. Nobody likes doing those. It makes no sense to me that apple has no support for this use-case. Oh well.